# Get first item in list in Power Automate Desktop

Tags: windows-10, power-automate

I'm trying to get the latest subfolder from a folder using Power Automate Desktop. I can get the list, and display it, that works fine. Then, I cant figure out how to get the first item. It's unbelievalbe that I cannot find out how to this simple task.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it works like index python.
You can call %list[0]% for first item.

refer this link for more info

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/desktop-flows/variable-data-types